# How to process txt with comma delimiter that also has comma as the thousands separator?

Tags: c++

Example of text:

> OUTPATIENT VISIT 4,Private,1,1,0,60,0,0
>   OUTPATIENT VISIT 4,Private,1,1,0,"1,260",0,0

At the moment I'm just separating the string like so:

```
std::stringstream ss(checkLine);

        getline(ss, something, ',');
        getline(ss, somethingElse, ',');
        getline(ss, somethingElse1, ',');
        getline(ss, somethingElse2, ','); 
        getline(ss, somethingElse3, ','); 
        getline(ss, somethingElse4, ','); 
        getline(ss, somethingElse5, ','); 
        getline(ss, somethingElse6, ',');
```

The way I'm doing it works for the first line of text but when it comes to the second line is goes to crap. There are a ton more lines its not only 2

I need to store each parsed section of the string onto its own string. How do I use the commas as delimiter and also deal with numbers using comma as a thousands separator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ 'Using space as a delimiter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597850/c-using-space-as-a-delimiter)

Comment: The only thing you have to do is replacing the space by a comma!

Comment: @strpeter : The duplicate you suggest would turn (in python notation) `'a "b c"'` into `['a', '"b', 'c"']`, the OP wants `['a', '"b c"']`

Comment: @MartinBonner: I understood the question the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the sequence `", "` as delimiter. By adding the space after the comma you filter out the second part of numbers.

Comment: oh i see. is there another way to do it the actual text im working with isnt as nice looking

Comment: @TentacleSlinger: Did you read this answer with sufficient care?

Comment: i didnt i redid my question :/ sorry

Comment: If you add a space after the comma ", " will filter out numbers like '2,000', as there is no space between the comma and the 0.

Comment: "Billing Office/Provider : doctor place P.SC., office location  ","Provider : Name, LAstname",Classification : No Classification,99215,OFFICE OUTPATIENT VISIT 4,Private,1,1,0,"1,060",0,0

Comment: Unfortunately `getline` only allows single character delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "," as delimiter and do a second pass where you will merge string containing digit (using std::isdigit per example).